# capture AJAX response

Tags: python, ajax, scrape

I want to scrape the following website: 
http://www.vaarweginformatie.nl/fdd/main/hydro/overview?contentId=HYDRO_WATERSTANDEN&pub=Hydro+waterstanden+-+rapport&detailPub=Hydro+waterstanden+-+detail&menuId=WATERSTANDEN/ajax

The information that I need is in the table and is provided using an ajax response. I can't seem to capture this response. I read Selenium might work but that it is also unstable, so I think this solution is not great since I want to set up a real time connection.

Are there other possibilities that I can try?

Comment: you need to scrape the ajax endpoint if you want data from it, unless your scraper can interpret js which I doubt. and staying clear from selenium is probably wise as it tends not to work very well with ajax heavy stuff

Comment: What is an ajax endpoint and how do I scrape it?

Comment: just go to your favorite browser console and see where does the ajax call get the data from and send a your scraper there too.